# how to use X-Win32 connect Mac OS in remote?

Tags: windows, macos, x11

Senario is:

One windows computer with X-Win32 application.
One mac os MBP  remotely.
How can I connect mac by using X-win32 in windows?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the app you mentioned, but it sounds like an X11 server. That won't do the job unless you want to remotely run an X11 app on your Mac, and export its display to your PC. Native Mac apps don't use X11.

You *can* run your Mac remotely though. Just enable desktop sharing on it, and connect to it with a VNC client.